# Cargar scripts con la función innerHtml o js nativo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy usando esta función para cargar código html en un div (hasta aquí funciona bien)

```
function changePage(pageUrl) {
$.ajax({
    url: pageUrl,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        // Verificar si la solicitud fue exitosa
        if (data) {
            // Insertar el contenido en divMain
            $('#mainDiv').html(data);
        } else {
            console.error("No se pudo cargar la página.");
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
}
```

Quiero hacer una función igual con js nativo (sin jquery) he probado a usar la función innerHtml pero al incluir scripts de la siguiente forma no me los carga

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./libs/js/earnings.min.js"></script>
```

Alguna idea?

Añado lo que he probado

```
function changePage(page){
var divMain = document.getElementById("mainDiv");

fetch(page)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
            return response.text();
        }
    })
    .then(data => {
        divMain.innerHTML = data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

}

Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Gorpe, por cada uno tenes que crear un elemento `script`. Es la única forma. Si dichos scripts no podes obtenerlos de otra forma, podrías buscarlos en el HTML y crearlos 1 x 1.

Comment: Securo que `#mainDiv` es una etiqueta script y no un div?

Answer (score -1):

Hay una solución aún más sencilla, sin utilizar librerías, en tu documento html pones lo siguiente:

```html
<div id=“pagina1”>
<!—- contenido —>
</div>
<div id=“pagina2”>
<!—- contenido —>
</div>
```

Si ya has hecho las paginas, ahora toca el JavaScript, que será una funcion más sencilla aún:

```javascript
function hideall() {
document.getElementById(‘pagina1’).style.display = “none”;
document.getElementById(‘pagina2’).style.display = “none”;
}
function cambiarpagina(iddelapagina) {
hideall()
document.getElementById(iddelapagina).style.display = “block”;
}
```

Ahora jamás con ejecutar la funcion cambiarpagina(pagina2) automáticamente se te cambiará escondiendo las demás

## Javi17mod

Comment: _[No uses firmas, taglines o saludos.](/help/behavior)_. ¿Qué quisiste decir en lugar de "jamás"? Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta. Aparte, ojo con el formato de las comillas...